# Trying to send an array to django database but get an error say Method not allow

Tags: javascript, django, charts, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to Django. I'm working on an app where the user types in the name of the activities and the times. It then displays it as a graph. When the user saves it, the data will end up being in a `JSON` format through serialization. My problem right now is that it only save the last value of the user input and not all the input. I'm trying to store an array into the Django database. I found multiple answers but none help. I figure to maybe make an HTTP request to send the value but any alternative will due.

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from page.templates.forms import ActivitiesForm
from page.models import Activities
from .serializers import ActivitiesSerializer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view()
def page_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        activities = Activities.objects.all()
        serializer = ActivitiesSerializer(activities, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ActivitiesSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

@csrf_protect
def page_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        activities = Activities.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Activities.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ActivitiesSerializer(activities)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ActivitesSerializer(activities, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        activities.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)

@csrf_protect
def page_show_view(request):
    a = Activities.objects.all()
    activities = serializers.serialize("json", a)
    return render(request, "page_show_view.html", {'activities':a})


def home_view(request, *args, **kargs):
    form = ActivitiesForm(request.POST or None)
   # context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "home_view.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
from base.models import CommonInfo
# Create your models here.
class Activities(CommonInfo):
    activity = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    time =     models.CharField(max_length = 15)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from .models import Activities

class ActivitiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity = serializers.CharField(max_length = 15)
    time =     serializers.CharField(max_length = 6)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Activities.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.activity = validated_data.get('activity', instance.activity)
        instance.time = validated_data.get('time', instance.time)
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Activities
        fields = ('activity', 'time')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from page import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('page/', views.page_list),
    path('page/<int:pk>/', views.page_detail),
]
```

**home_view.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <main>  
        <div>
            <h1>Time Management</h1>
            <form action='/page/'method='POST' autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}    
                <select name="" id="Time">
                    <option value="Select" default>Select time</option>
                    <option value="Hours" id="hours">Hours</option>
                    <option value="Min" id="Min">Minutes</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="button" id="ActivityButton" value="Add Activity" onclick="addValue()">
                <input type="submit" id="ActivityButton" value="Save">
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**app.js**

```
let hour = 24

// declare chart variable and dataSet variable
var chart, dataSet;

anychart.onDocumentLoad(function () {
  // create an instance of a pie chart
  chart = anychart.pie();
  // create dataSet and add some initial data
  dataSet = anychart.data.set(["Undocumented time", hour]);
  // set the inital data
  chart.data(dataSet);
  chart.innerRadius("30%");

   chart.background().fill({
     keys: ["whitesmoke"]
 });

  // set the container element and draw 
  chart.container("container").draw();

   // create and configure a label
 var label = anychart.standalones.label();
 label.text("Activities");
 label.width("100%");
 label.height("80%");
 label.fontColor("white");
 label.hAlign("center");
 label.vAlign("middle");

 // set the label as the center content
 chart.center().content(label);
});
// set data to chart when user performs an action
function addValue(){
  var minPerc = 60
  var minCalc;

  // read values from inputs
  var name = document.getElementById('id_activity').value;
  var value = document.getElementById('id_time').value;
  var option = document.getElementById('Time').value;

  // appendn name value pair to dataSet
  if(hour > 0){
    if(option == "Min"){
      //Set hour
      minCalc = value / minPerc
      hour = hour - minCalc;

      dataSet.row(1, ["Undocumented time", hour])
      dataSet.append([name, minCalc]);
    }
    else if(option == "Hours"){
      hour = hour - value;

      dataSet.row(1, ["Undocumented time", hour])
      dataSet.append([name, value]); 
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                  cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return cookieValue;
  }

  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/page/", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(dataSet.jc))
    console.log(dataSet.jc)

  }  
}
```

**Question:**

> Keep getting error message say method not allowed: /page/[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvMMi.png)
>   Any alternative is very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to send an array to django api but get an error say Method not allow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357950/trying-to-send-an-array-to-django-api-but-get-an-error-say-method-not-allow)

Answer (score 0):

See [@api_view() docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view).

By default only GET methods will be accepted. You need to change your line to:

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def page_list(request):
   # your code here
```

Comment: Ok I did that than i get a Bad Request: /page/ error

Comment: @GersonAreche it's because your line ```if serializer.is_valid():``` return ```False```. You configured this server response by yourself. Try to find out what errors with your  ```serializer```. Printing errors will be good first step.